# Convertir JSON complejo a DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

**Descripción:**

Estoy desarrollando una solución web en [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) para que, desde el front armar un objeto `JSON` complejo para que, al recibirlo en el back, guardar los valores en una base de datos SQL Server 2012.

El objeto `JSON` complejo está compuesto de la siguiente manera:

```
[{
    "__KEY__": "73c14f5b-cbb9-8711-217a-a1a5453b7159",
    "sUserID": [80417452, 80426837, 79945118],
    "FechaInicio": "2017-04-19T05:00:00.000Z",
    "FechaFin": "2017-04-20T05:00:00.000Z",
    "Id_Franja": 3
}]
```

Al usar las siguientes líneas para serializar el objeto JSON y convertirlo a *`DataTable`* obtengo este resultado:

*Código:*

```
// La variable "myJson" contiene el JSON complejo.
DataTable jsonDataTable = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myJson, (typeof(DataTable)));
```

*Resultado de la serialización:*

[image: Resultado serializar JSON]

Debo convertir este JSON complejo a un DataTable en C#; en este caso, necesito que los valores de la columna "sUserID" estén en el *`DataTable`* como un string separado por comas.

¿Cómo convertir este objeto JSON complejo en un DataTable?

---

He intentado [estas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28450599/4092887) [soluciones](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39178208/4092887), pero no logro ajustar el código para lograr este objetivo.

Estoy buscando otras opciones para convertir objetos JSON complejos *"como el del ejemplo"* en DataTable.

Comment: Sí necesitas que se guarde como un solo string, separado por comas, porqué agregas [], xq no lo manejas como el resto de campos, usando comillas

Comment: Hola Mauricio, una pregunta, ¿el `DataTable` lo requieres para posteriormente llenar un `DataGrid`?

Comment: Hola @Flxtr, el DataTable lo necesito para recorrerlo y guardar los datos en base de datos. el DataTable lo utilizo como variable.

Comment: Hola @RandallSandoval, no estoy seguro si te entiendo bien. espero que [mi comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/65961/convertir-json-complejo-a-datatable?noredirect=1#comment120413_65961) sea un poco mas claro.

Comment: @RandallSandoval se refiere al segundo párrafo de la respuesta que justo acabo de publicar :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El elemento `sUserID` se muestra de esa forma ya que el mismo compilador determina el tipo y detecta qe es un `array` de `int64[]`, y al no poder mostrar el contenido, solo muestra el tipo de dato.

Si ese valor pudiese venir como `"sUserID": "[80417452, 80426837, 79945118]"`, entonces sí lo podrá determinar como un `string`.

Ahora, antes de deserializarlo directamente a un `DataTable`, es mejor convertirlo a un `List<T>`, para que a partir de esa lista la manejemos como la fuente de datos.

Definición de la clase:

```
public class jsonContent
{
    public string __KEY__ { get; set; }
    public int[] sUserID { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaInicio { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaFin { get; set; }
    public int Id_Franja { get; set; }
    public string sUserIdNuevo
    {
        get
        {
            return String.Join("", new List<int>(this.sUserID).ConvertAll(i => i.ToString()).ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

Nota que al no poder convertir `sUserID` directamente a `string` nos apoyaremos de otra variable llamada `sUserIdNuevo` y lo que hará es concatenar los valores del `array` de `int64[]` con `String.Join("", new List<int>(this.sUserID).ConvertAll(i => i.ToString()).ToArray());`

Dado a tu comentario que solo utilizas el `DataTable` para recorrerlo y usarlo como variable para el almacenamiento a la base de datos, sugiero que recorras la lista y con eso sería suficiente:

```
List<jsonContent> jsonDataTable = (List<jsonContent>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myJson, (typeof(List<jsonContent>)));

foreach (jsonContent item in jsonDataTable)
{
    //Aquí va toda la lógica de guardado a la base de datos
}
```

[Este artículo](https://dzone.com/articles/reasons-move-datatables) (*en inglés*) indica 7 poderosas razones por las cuales cambiar `DataTable` por colecciones genéricas.

Comment: Parece que si tendré que cambiar el DataTable por una lista _tal como muestras en tu pregunta_. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave en lo personal se me hace mucho más sencillo trabajar con listas, a eso le añades el uso de Linq, uffff, el performance mejora de manera significativa, sobre todo te das cuenta cuando trabajas con grandes cantidades de datos. Me alegra que te haya servido  mi respuesta :D